# Spring UserDetail field getting populated incorrectly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

So I am facing a weird issue with my application after upgrading Spring 2.5 to Spring 3.0. We have a form backing bean.let's call it, `BackingBean.java`. This bean has a field:

```
private String userState;
```

Now for our security, the UserDetails implementation looks something like:

```
public class UserBean implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    private String userState;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userId;
    private String userDistinguishedName;
```

**Now the issue**, there's a form in the application with a field backed by `userState` from `BackingBean`,

```
<spring:bind path="backingBean.userState">
```

anytime the form is submitted, the same value is getting filled into userState in `UserBean` object as well. This wasn't the case with Spring 2.5. Not sure what caused it and where to start debugging this?
Any pointers will be highly helpful.

Comment: Writing a useful title will get your question more attention and make it helpful to other users who find this page via other means, like a google search. [Here's how to write a good one.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: Is there a reason you're upgrading to 3.0 instead of 4.1?

Comment: Can't you remove or renamed UserBean.userState?

Comment: @chrylis, All upgrades are shoved down from enterprise team. We don't have a say. 4.0 will probably come in couple of years for us. Lol